# Regenerate NuGet repositories.config manually

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way how to manually regenerate NuGet `repositories.config` for a particular solution?

**Edit:**

Updating any package explicitly to the same version will eventually regenerate `repositories.config`, but will update the package configurations in every project within the solution as well. I am looking for a cleaner way how to do this.

For instance, when having `Newtonsoft.Json` version `6.0.8` and "updating" explicitly with `Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.8`.